# Reading and Converting Series of images to Numpy Array With Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, keras, computer-vision

I am trying to read the images from different sub-directories and turned them to Numpy array. I have the path of each directory along the image names in a text file, in the first, third and fourth column. Once the subdirectory of images changes, the shape of array would turn from 4D to 1D, for example from (1316, 112, 112, 3) to (1423,). I don't understand why this happens and what is wrong with my code. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
img/doc/pic1 83 000001 0001276
img/doc/pic1 0  001277 001316
img/doc/pic2 83 000001 000107
```

so after reading the third line, the output would be (1423,)

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
f = open("Subject.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
all_images = []
for item in lines:
    line_parts = item.strip().split()
    path = line_parts[0]
    start = int(line_parts[2])
    end =  int(line_parts[3])
    for image_path in sorted(os.listdir(path))[start-1:end]:
           print(image_path)
           im = cv2.imread(path + "/" + image_path)
           all_images.append(im)
    x = np.array(all_images)
    print(x.shape)
```

Comment: I'm guessing what is happening is that the pic1 and pic2 images are different sizes, but you're trying to put them in an array together. You can't have shape (N, 112, 112, 3) for the first 1k values and then shape (N, 256, 256, 3) for the next 1k values and so on. Are they different sizes? Why do you need them all in an array at once?

Comment: Yes you were right. The images in other sub-directories were different than the first two ones! I want to store all of them in an array for x-train in keras. And I want to have the second column as the label to be the y_train! Do you think storing them all at once is the wrong approach?

Comment: Well, you can't have arrays with varying dimensions of course---an array where two rows are different lengths isn't an array at all. Depending on the model, it is common to resize all inputs to the same size, but that all depends. If the model supports arbitrary sizes, then likely Keras has a way to read a list of images, or similar, where each image can be an arbitrary size.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make use of [`flow_from_dataframe`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_dataframe) method which makes image processing super easy. Simply:

1. Create a pandas data frame with two columns: `image path` and `label`. To avoid issues, put absolute image path.
2. Then for validation, simply split the dataframe using `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`
3. Finally, `flow_from_dataframe` to generate arrays and training the model using `.fit_generator` method.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @YOLO... However the structure of my data is a little bit confusing and complicated! for example in one path, I have sequence of images with three different labels! so I have a case where the path(s) is being repeated through the csv/txt file with different labels. Do you think Is that Ok to remove the start and end frames? I had doubts that's why I put the start and end frame in each row!

Comment: Also for step 2, I have to turn the image to numpy array and store it as 'x' otherwise how I can use the `sklearn split`

Comment: I see you have images, I think for your case set `class_mode = multi_output`, you don't have to convert images to array, keras will take care of it, just make sure the dataframe is made correctly, it's super easy. do check the documentation.